Why can't I publish a static webpage on Github or see it in pages anymore?
I dont see the publish option anymore anywhere once my repo is uploaded
Im following official instructions https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site, but this option to publish to pages never appears
Ive done this before a dozen times with old github. Im publishing a static webpage that worked before
Where can I find the option to publish pages on this new version of github, because it is not where the manual specifies it is
I don’t see the publish option anywhere once my repository is uploaded. I’ve followed the official instructions from GitHub’s documentation on creating a GitHub Pages site, but the option to publish to Pages never appears. I’ve checked multiple times, but it’s nowhere to be found.
I’ve successfully used GitHub Pages in the past, so I’m familiar with the process. I’ve been using GitHub for a while and have published several static webpages before, so this is a bit unusual. Everything seems to be in place, but I just can’t find the publish option.
The repository I’m trying to use for this page is set up correctly. All the files are in the right location, and the webpage worked perfectly before on the old GitHub interface. However, with the new version, I’m unsure where the changes have been made to the UI that might affect the Pages publishing process.
I’ve read through the official documentation, but the manual specifies a location for the publish option that I cannot find in the new version of GitHub. I’m following all the steps, but the expected option isn’t appearing.
Can you help me figure out where to find the option to publish a GitHub Pages site in this new version of GitHub? I’ve been looking for it for a while, and it’s frustrating not to see it where it was in the past.

This is all I see

